# CAPL check between two char arrays

Tags: arrays, char, capl

I have a question regarding some CAPL programming. I am looking to check between two arrays. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Can i please have some help. I have The following code:

```
void Check(char out[])
{
char checker[8] = "2e7f2e";
if(checker == out )
{
...
}
}
```

Can you please help me on how to check the two arrays?

Answer (score 2):

CAPL is - mostly - C

You can use, e.g.

```
if(strncmp(out, checker, 8) == 0) {
  ...
}
```